# shutil.rmtree to remove files only?

Tags: python

I am using `shutil.rmtree` to remove a directory, but other processes (that I don't control) that create files in that tree are failing to create the files because the directories don't exist. Is there something as easy as `shutil.rmtree` that only deletes files but preserves directory structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in function to do this, but you could easily do it yourself using [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(my_directory):
    # Remove regular files, ignore directories
    for filename in filenames:
        os.unlink(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

Comment: I think you need `os.path.join(my_directory, dirpath, filename)`, don't you?

Comment: Not according to the [os.walk](documentation). Relevant fragment _To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name)._

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in one line, and you have GNU find, outsource:

```
subprocess.check_call(["find", "-H", directory, "!", "-type", "d", "-delete"])
```

This also has the advantage of having been very carefully coded by experts to avoid a number of race conditions which can allow a malicious process on the same system to trick your process into deleting something it shouldn't have.  I don't think it's actually possible to avoid *all* of those races using `os.walk`; you need an API that lets you use [`unlinkat`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/unlinkat) or [`fchdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fchdir).

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this:

```
import os

def rm_files_in_tree(dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for file in files:
            path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
            os.remove(path)
```